# Using SQL LINQ to update a table (performing slowly)

Tags: c#, linq

The code below works.  But, I think I am doing it wrong because it is running slowly.  I am iterating through a list of customer records to determine if anything has changed, or if anything has been added.  I am using LINQ, along with two FOREACH loops.  The first FOREACH is needed, but the second one is simply searching for the record to verify (10 to 20 records).  Am I missing a search method?

```
  var ResultSKUConnection = from a in SKUConnections
                            where ((a.Customer_ID == Cust_ID) && (a.Connection_Name == "eBay") && (a.Item_ID == item.ItemID))
                            select a;
  foreach (VariationType varitem in item.Variations.Variation)
  {
     Boolean found = false;
     foreach (SKUConnection SKUitem in ResultSKUConnection)
     {
        if (SKUitem.SKU==varitem.SKU)
        {
           found = true;
           Console.WriteLine($"Found  Item ID {item.ItemID}, SKU {varitem.SKU}");
           if (SKUitem.eBay_Price != varitem.StartPrice.Value || SKUitem.eBay_Price_Currency != varitem.StartPrice.currencyID.ToString())
           {
              SKUitem.eBay_Price = varitem.StartPrice.Value;
              SKUitem.eBay_Price_Currency = varitem.StartPrice.currencyID.ToString();
              Console.WriteLine($"UPDATE  Item ID {item.ItemID}, SKU {varitem.SKU}");
           }
           break;
        }
     }
     if (!found)
     {
        SKUConnection NewSKU = new SKUConnection();
        NewSKU.SKU = varitem.SKU;
        NewSKU.eBay_Price = varitem.StartPrice.Value;
        NewSKU.eBay_Price_Currency = varitem.StartPrice.currencyID.ToString();
        NewSKU.eBay_VariationSpecifics = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(varitem.VariationSpecifics);
        SKUConnections.InsertOnSubmit(NewSKU);
        Console.WriteLine($"ADD  Item ID {item.ItemID}, SKU {varitem.SKU}");
     }
  }
  db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: You use `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` class to identify which part of your code is slow. Is it the select linq query because of poor indexing? Is it the nested loop? or is it the `!found` block? Try isolating the issue first. Your nested loop is most likely the cause of poor performance.

Comment: Like Ephraim said, the double for loop most likely causes the issue, especially with a large amount of items in your lists. I would suggest creating a list with using .Where(x => ResultSKUConnection.Select(s => s.SKU).Contains(x.SKU)); But again like Ephraim said, time the performance and try a few functions.